# C# program is not running after publishing (.dll problem?)

Tags: c#

My Programm which uses avicap32.dll for a Webcam Capture run on my Windows 10 dev computer without problems, but when I want to use the published version on another computer (Windows 7, no updates activated, offline) the program runs, but as soon I try to capture a picture from the camera, it doesn't work. I get an exception thrown and that's it. (Also I get a black image from the webcam, I double checked that the webcam is connected and accessible).

To add avicap32.dll I used the following code:

```cs
//This call is one of the most important and is vital to the operation of the OS.
[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

//This API creates the webcam instance so we can access it.
[DllImport("avicap32.dll", EntryPoint = "capCreateCaptureWindowA")]
public static extern int capCreateCaptureWindowA(string lpszWindowName, int dwStyle, int x, int y, int nWidth, int nHeight, int hwndParent, int nID);

//This API opens the clipboard so we can fetch webcam data.
[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "OpenClipboard")]
public static extern int OpenClipboard(int hWnd);

//This API cleans the clipboard.
[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "EmptyClipboard")]
public static extern int EmptyClipboard();

//This API closes the clipboard after use.
[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "CloseClipboard")]
public static extern int CloseClipboard();

//This API retrieves the data from the clipboard for use.
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
extern static IntPtr GetClipboardData(uint uFormat);

//This API is needed to execute the picture indication
[DllImport("cvextern.dll")]
extern static int MyFunction()
```

This is the function that captures the image and saves it:

```cs
public void Capture_Image() {
    try {
        ImageSize();
        m_CapHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA("WebCap", 0, 0, 0, m_Width, m_Height, Handle.ToInt32(), 0);
        SendMessage(m_CapHwnd, WM_CAP_CONNECT, 0, 0);
        SendMessage(m_CapHwnd, WM_CAP_GT_FRAME, 0, 0);
        SendMessage(m_CapHwnd, WM_CAP_COPY, 0, 0);
        OpenClipboard(m_CapHwnd);
        CloseClipboard();
        SendMessage(m_CapHwnd, WM_CAP_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);

        Image tempImg = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetData("Bitmap");
        pictureBox2.Image = tempImg;
        pictureBox2.Refresh();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        fileName = "C:/FHT59N3/Bildanalyse_Projekt/image.jpg";
        Clipboard.GetImage().Save(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    catch (NullReferenceException) {
        string message = "No Camera found";
        string title = "Please connect Camera";
        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
        MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }
}
```

Are there special settings I have to set to make it run on Windows 7?

Comment: is that dll on the other machine and registered?

Comment: Exceptions and their messages are the only way you can work out whats going wrong, why did you choose not paste it?. please show us the information you have, and any clue as to why this is not working

Comment: BugFinder: I searched for it but on a fast search in could not find it. Are the necessary DLLs no directly in the Programm included when the programm is published?
Michael Randall: As you can see i can catch the NullReferenceException so i get the message "No Camera Found". This is common when there is no camera connected to the Machine. The strange thing is that i get a Dialog Window where i can choose the cam, but after clicking OK i get that exception thrown

Comment: Did you show really ALL your declares? And hopefully, you did NOT deploy your win10 avi... to a win7 installation? As far as I can see from a (old vb6 sample), you need to sendmessage first to get a capwindow handle (WAP_CAP_DLG_VIDEOFORMAT), then connect to the driver (also by sending a message WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT) and than send messages to grab a frame WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME and ... forwhatever reason: WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY

Comment: @BugFinder That's not an ActiveX DLL so doesn't need to be registered. Your point about it being in place is likely salient though.

Comment: nabuchodonossor: no sorry i add all my declares on the dll's now. No i thot that deploying an win10 dll to win 7 wasn't a good idea so i did not do that

Comment: @Qbex_12b: thanks for replying, so we can exclude some of the possible reasons.

Comment: I managed it now (you still did not include the complete necessary block) to compile this program .... but: In my virtual developer pc, I get only a "grey" image. But not an exception. And after copied the exe to my physical desktop pc, it just took an picture .... worked fine. But, to be honest, my virtual developer pc is running on w7, while my physical pc is w10 .... the opposite of your configuration

Answer (score -1):

This is not a solution to your problem per se, but it's too long to fit in the comment box either.

---

You might want to consider removing

```
GC.Collect(); 
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

as it's almost always better to use [`SafeHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?view=netframework-4.7.2)s where possible and / or [the `IDisposable` pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.7.2) when dealing with unmanaged resources.

`GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();` blocks program execution until all finalizers are run, and it *can* introduce deadlocks. `GC.Collect();` can also slow down your program noticably because it tries to collect *all generations* - contrary to what happens on a normal GC run. It also has a high overload too, because it needs to stop all threads (= block program execution) and walk all object graphs to find memory that can be collected. Every object that cannot be collected right now will be promoted to the next generation, which means that your program hangs on to memory that would not actually be required anymore for longer than necessary.

---

<sub>For more information, see the "Remarks" section of [`GC.Collect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_GC_Collect#Remarks) as well as the "Remarks" section of [`GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks).</sub>

<sub>See also [When to call `GC.Collect`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/2004/11/29/when-to-call-gc-collect/) - rule number 1 is "Don't".</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Okay i got a solution. I changed reading process from using external Dlls to using the OpenCV commands. Works fine. Even a few less codelines.

This is now my code to Read the Webcam:

```
public void Capture_Image()
    {
        try
        {
            capture = new VideoCapture();
            Bitmap tempImg = capture.QueryFrame().Bitmap;
            pictureBox2.Image = null;
            pictureBox2.Image = tempImg;
            pictureBox2.Refresh();
            tempImg.Save("C:/FHT59N3/Bildanalyse_Projekt/image.jpg");

            tempImg.Dispose();
            capture.Dispose();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            string message = "No Camera found";
            string title = "Please connect Camera";
            MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;
            MessageBox.Show(message, title, buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```